# How to separate parts of list item into a new list?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, pyserial

I want to grab the return data from one of my function and create a new list holding the two values contained in the initial list as indexes for a new list.

What I'm currently trying is: I get a response from my serial port, I store the response data in a variable and then I perform a `.split(' ')`  (assuming this will return a list holding items that were separated with a space) and it did.

**What I'm trying to get is this:**  `gax = ['110.00', '94.00']`

**My response without the `.split(' ')` method:**

```
b'[06][1c]ans=33[0d] job=42985[0d] mid=001[0d] status=0;&quot;ok&quot;[0d]do=b[0d] crib=69.80;67.80[0d] gax=110.00;94.00[0d][1e][1d]'
```

**My data *with* the `.split(' ')` method:**

```
['[06][1c]ans=33[0d]', 'job=42985[0d]', 'mid=001[0d]',
 'status=0;&quot;ok&quot;[0d]do=b[0d]', 'crib=69.80;67.80[0d]',
 'gax=110.00;94.00[0d][1e][1d]']
```

**and this is what I get when I tried a list comprehension:**

```
['g', 'a', 'x', '=', '1', '1', '0', '.', '0', '0', ';', '9', '4', '.', '0', '0',
 '[', '0', 'd', ']', '[', '1', 'e', ']', '[', '1', 'd', ']']
```

How can I achieve what I want to do?
Is list comprehension the right way to go?

```
def get_job_from_serial():
    response_f = serial_client.readline()
    print('job sent from host {}'.format(response_f))
    return response_f

jrfromserial = get_job_from_serial()
j = jrfromserial.decode('utf-8').split(' ')
print('la lista de strings disponible son ------ >> {}'.format(j))

# here I was trying to remove the trailing part in brackets.
# what I got was gax=110.00;94.
pre_gax = j[5].rstrip('[0d][1e][1d]]')
print(pre_gax)

gax = [g for g in j[5]]
print(gax)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you're getting is because you're looping through a string value which will give you a list of characters

To resolve your gax issue you should just be able to do:

```
gax_nums = pre_gax.lstrip("gax=")
gax = [float(x) for x in gax_nums.split(";")]
```